# jQuery not reading selected option after refresh

Tags: jquery, local-storage, html-select

Morning,

I have a select box which looks like this:

```
<select id="companyselect" name="companyselect">
<option value="-1">Please choose company</option>
<option value="CO1">CO1</option>
<option value="CO2">CO2</option>
<option value="CO3">CO3</option>
<option value="CO4">CO4</option>
</select>
```

All options, apart from the first, are generated using jQuery (from localStorage) and appear as they should.

I have a jquery function which is triggered on the 'change' event:

```
$(document).on('change', '#companyselect', function(e){
    thecomp = $('#companyselect').val();
    alert(thecomp);
});
```

This all works fine.

However, when I reload the page, all options are generated as expected but the 'change' event is not working as required. No matter what option is selected, `$('#companyselect').val();` is always returned as the first option.

I have checked the DOM to see if there is another element with the same id, but no.
I have tried returning the text of the option, and it returns the text of the first option.

All suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, which somebody put on here but then deleted, is to replace

```
thecomp = $('#companyselect').val();
```

with

```
thecomp = $(this).val();
```

Thanks to whomever posted the answer originally

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you use localstorage to get the selected value even after use refreshes the page using jquery using [localstorage](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/),

```
$(document).on('change', '#companyselect', function(e){
var thecomp = $('#companyselect').val();
localStorage.thecomp=thecomp;
alert(thecomp);
});

    if(localStorage.getItem('thecomp')){
     alert(localStorage.thecomp);   
    $("#companyselect").val(localStorage.thecomp);
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/33/)**

Comment: what do you mean? Check the fiddle, the value is changed everytime you change the value of select menu

Comment: Thanks, I decided not to use localStorage.thecomp as I do not need that stored

Comment: So what were you looking for? The value is changed right? and it is alerted on every change?

Comment: Yes. See my answer below :-)